# Is the difference between "changesets" and "snapshots" in version control primarily a space-time tradeoff?

Tags: design, version-control

There are many version control systems out there, and they tend to use one of the following models to store separate versions of a repository:

1. Snapshots - each version of your repository is stored in its entirety, i.e. if you make changes to file1.txt, there are two stored versions of `file1.txt` representing the different versions.
2. Changesets - the first version of your repository is considered the "root", and any subsequent versions are recorded as changes from the root. E.g. if you change `file1.txt`, it's not stored twice, only the difference between your new version and the root version is stored.

Git uses snapshots - kind of. Although each commit is stored as a separate version, it uses delta compression under the hood to save space. But it seems like [there's a fairly even split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version-control_software#Technical_information) between VCSes which use snapshot-based storage and changeset-based storage.

So what I understand from this is that there is a trade-off between VCSes that use changeset storage, and those that use snapshot based storage. And that's a trade-off between storage space and processing speed.

- If you have a repository with many objects (e.g. thousands or millions of code files,) then a purely snapshot-based versioning system would end up with repositories ballooning in size, as each version of each file has to be stored separately whenever there are changes.
- If you have a repository where each file has many revisions (e.g. you have thousands, or say millions of commits), then a purely changeset-based versioning system would struggle with processing speed, as building a commit would require trawling through millions of commits to piece together a complete file.

I get the impression that most VCSes will have some mechanisms in place to mitigate around both of these problems - like Git which isn't purely snapshot based and "kind of" uses changesets under the hood. But from what I understand, the basic trade-off between these two forms of storage in version control systems is between performance and space. Changeset-based versioning systems do well to optimise space by storing less redundant data for your repository (because whole files are never stored twice.) Snapshot-based versioning systems do well to optimise performance - because it doesn't have to trawl through chains of deltas to construct the state of your repository.

The question is simply: **is this understanding correct, or are there other important trade-offs between changeset-based versioning and snapshot-based versioning?**

---

The motivation for the question / XY problem is this: I am interested in sketching a design for a VCS, and am contemplating whether to design using changesets or snapshots. As far as I see it the main reason to choose one or the other is space or time, and then optimise around your chosen trade-off. But I am wondering whether there is more to the design decision than these factors.

Comment: The core of your question is not unlike a similar discussion on event sourced architectures.

Comment: @Flater - Could you please elaborate, or do you perhaps have a link to the discussion?

Comment: Event sourced data stores store events (mutations of the original object). However, due to the cost of replaying (imagine having to individually replay a list of 100 items you're fetching), it's advised to either store the last known state (snapshot), or make milestone snapshots (e.g. weekly, every X events, ...). There's a fair amount of discussion on this topic in general (I think I gave you enough keywords to look up some resources) which may prove interesting to you.

Comment: I think you did not describe "Changesets" right. They typically don't store differences between the "root" and newer revisions. They store the differences between two sequential revisions, as well as the "latest revision" in full, not the "first revision". That makes the performance of a commit not depend on the number of former revisions of a file. The performance drawbacks only come in play when one tries to access older revisions from the past - newer revisions can be reconstructed quickly by applying the changeset in reverse order, old ones require more time.

Comment: ... however, to give you quick answer: I think you are right, Changesets vs. Snapshots is just trading time for space. But as with every kind of redundancy in storage systems, there is also the aspect of additional security against data loss: a purely "Changeset" based system will be more fragile against the loss of a single file than a system which uses "Snapshots".